# User Inteface problem: A way to get MDI Children to show up in taskbar?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'd like your advice on the following issue: We are studying different User Interface solutions for an Windows Forms application we are developing and we have come to the conclusion that the best solution seems to me a Single Document Interface the way MS Word does it: That is, each time we create a new document it will open in a new "main" window and the process is killed when all "main" windows are closed.

However, the way MS Excel approaches the MDI interface is also interesting and, due to the way our application works, it could be a good solution. The problem is that this solution seems to be more complicated due to one main reason: Showing MDI Child Forms in the task bar.

So my question is the following: can anybody give me some advice on how to get MDI Children to show up in the task bar. I'm almost certain there is absolutely no way to do it from the .NET Framework. I've been studying ways to go looking at the relevant Windows API but I don't seem to see an obvious way to try and get to what we want.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention app targets mainly Win XP platform.

Comment: It depends on what versions of Windows you'd like to support. Windows 7's taskbar offers multiple thumbnails per application icon to represent MDI documents.

Comment: @BoltClock: I edited the question. My app targets mainly Win XP

Comment: Winforms doesn't support it because Windows doesn't support it.  XP only supports taskbar buttons for toplevel windows.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Windows supports it because MS Excel works that way. Another issue is that it cant be done with the Windows API we have at our disposal.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that there is no way to do this directly from C# as this functionality is not implemented in the .Net Fx, but rather in the Windows API. Luckily Microsoft provides a managed library to access these functions in Windows 7 (and some Windows Vista ones). Take a look at the [Windows API Code Pack for Microsoft .Net Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). The functionality you are looking for is called **Tabbed Thumbnails**.

Answer (score 1):

By design, children of an MDI form do not show up in the Taskbar. It's best to stick to this principle.

On Windows 7, you can add a 'thumbnail' for an MDI child to the task bar but this functionality is not available directly in .net. You can check MSDN for the additional APIs.

There is a work-around, though: when selecting a form you can detach it from the MDI parent. You have to make sure that it is re-attached when a new child form is selected. Add the following code to your MDI container form:

```
    private Form focusedChild;

    private void CreateWindow()
    {
        Form window = new Form();
        window.GotFocus += new EventHandler(Child_GotFocus);
        window.Show();
    }

    void Child_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form window = sender as Form;

        if (null != window)
        {
            if (focusedChild != null && window!=focusedChild)
            {
                focusedChild.SuspendLayout();
                focusedChild.MdiParent = null;
                focusedChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                focusedChild.ResumeLayout();
            }


            window.SuspendLayout();
            window.MdiParent = this;
            window.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            window.ResumeLayout();

            focusedChild = window;
        }
    }
```

I would not recommend this, however. Stick to the default behaviour, or look at the Windows 7 thumbnails if your app will run on Windows 7.

Comment: See KilZone's answer - just ahead of me, and with the correct link to the Windows 7 API.

Comment: My gripe with MDI interface is that there is no indication to the user on how many windows are open. MS Excel fixes that beautifully showing the MDI children in the taskbar. I was wondering how they managed to do that in Win XP.

Comment: Judging by the way Excel looks on my machine (Excel 2010 on Win7) it's not really MDI but a custom-drawn thing. Then again, Microsoft Office has had a custom look for some time now, ahead of other Microsoft applications, let alone the rest of us that are limited to what the .NET and Win32 APIs make available to us.

Comment: I have found a hack. It should work fine on XP. For Win7, you'd need to implement the API described by KilZone, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but works in XP. In Windows 7 it doesn't look too good, so you'd need to implement the tabbed thumbnails API instead.

Basically, it creates an invisible surrogate form for each MDI child control, and when a surrogate receives focus (when you select it in the task bar) it passes it on to the appropriate child window.

Assuming an MDI container named Form1, this code will do that:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateWindow("child 1");
        CreateWindow("child 2");
    }

    private void CreateWindow(string name)
    {
        Form window = new Form();
        window.MdiParent = this;
        window.Text = name;
        window.Show();

        Form surrogate = new Form();
        surrogate.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        surrogate.Text = name;
        surrogate.Show(this);
        surrogate.Size = Size.Empty;
        surrogate.GotFocus += new EventHandler(surrogate_GotFocus);

        surrogate.Tag = window;
        window.Tag = surrogate;
    }

    void surrogate_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form surrogate = sender as Form;
        if (null != surrogate && null != surrogate.Tag)
        {
            Form target = surrogate.Tag as Form;
            target.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Again, I don't think straying from the design is a good thing here. You're better off sticking to the MDI restrictions, and implementing the appropriate APIs on newer OS installations. If you really need the windows to show up in the task bar, then you can use a hack such as this.

Comment: I thought about this solution but it has one big flaw. The surrogates aren't really the selected Mdi Children so there will be no visible feedback of which document is the currently active document in the task bar.

Comment: True. It's just a hack, in the end. :-(