# "Taskbar" in my MDI app?

Tags: c#, controls, taskbar

I was wondering if there was a way to simulate the taskbar in my MDI app? It's mainly for aesthetic purposes, because when I minimise the child forms, this is what I get:

[image]

And to me, that looks ugly. I know you can make it so that the child forms will appear in the task bar, but I don't want that.

I want to try an imitate the taskbar *within* my app. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [User Inteface problem: A way to get MDI Children to show up in taskbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167155/user-inteface-problem-a-way-to-get-mdi-children-to-show-up-in-taskbar)

Comment: @gunr2171 hmm, no... I'm looking to create the taskbar *within* the Main form of my MDI app to show the child forms. Not on the windows taskbar (or whatever OS you are using).