# Show in TaskBar C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to see from when I click on Alt + tab ,I set showtaskbar = true but nothing happened
I call the form by this code

```
  childForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            childForm.MaximizeBox = false;
            childForm.MinimizeBox = false;
            childForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            childForm.ControlBox = false;
            childForm.MdiParent = MdiParent;
            childForm.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            childForm.ShowIcon = true;
            childForm.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 1360, 5);
            childForm.Show();
```

Comment: An MDI child is never shown in the taskbar. Only the parent container form (MDIParent) is. You can still switch from one mdi child to another using, I think, <Strg + Tab>, when the Parent is active.

Comment: how can i show it after using alt + tab??

Comment: <Alt + Tab> will always address the MdiParent only. It is switching between Applications, not their subwindows.

Answer (score 1):

This is behavior by design.

quoting from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx:

> If a form is parented within another form, the parented form is not displayed in the Windows taskbar.

If you need multiple windows of one application shown in the taskbar, don't use MdiParent/MdiChild.

There is a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167484/1132334) which may work for you, but it is likely not sustainable (may break in future versions of Windows).